# How to add 500 IP address (Range of IP) in Network File for single interface

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, ip, ifconfig, ip-address

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS was what I was using.
How can a single interface be configured with a 500 IP address ( Ranges of IP address) ?
For example
I need to configure 101.23.151.0/24 and 101.24.152.0/24
There is an excessive delay when adding IP addresses one by one in the network file. Is there a way to add them quickly? Could you recommend a quicker and more efficient method for permanently configuring several IP addresses?
and what was the option that we had to use in order to boot up the IP while booting the server ?
I was provided with the below network file:
PATH:  /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
        - 101.75.13.191/32
        - 101.75.13.192/32
      routes:
        - on-link: true
          to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 38.75.136.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 2001:4860:4860::8844
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 2001:4860:4860::8888
```

---

Hereby, I'll outline the procedure I previously used in CentOS 7 to set up numerous IP addresses below.

```
cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/

vim  ifcfg-enp0s3-range0
IPADDR_START=23.82.132.2
IPADDR_END=23.82.132.60
CLONENUM_START=0
GATEWAY=23.82.132.62
PREFIX=26
```

I need to know what the similar configuration in Ubuntu 20 is that I already use in CentOS as this arrangement helps me to quickly increase the ranges of IPs at times.